# Any option to view history of Resolution Center communications - iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

One of my old app version is rejected by apple saying, `Additional Information Needed` that *"Can you please specify, what feature of the app uses iTunes File Sharing?"*. Then I convinced them through my replies and successfully released the app.

Now with my latest release again I met a similar situation, so I would like to go through my `old Resolution Centre communications`. Can anyone help me to get through this?

**Note:** After my research I found there is an option in iTunes-Connect to get the history of the veriosn status.

> MyApp -> Activity -> App Store Version

above steps will list all the versions of the app, By expanding it will list all the status of the version which that gone through. I can see there is the status `'Metadata Rejected'` but there is no link that direct to `Resolution Centre conversation`.

So can anyone help me to find where is the *history of Resolution Centre communications*?

Comment: As i know that you need to give them same proof what you given at last time. they can not take care what happens with last time. so better to make a video and up it at you-tube and show them about app features.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but @Nitin its a huge project with so many features its not easily possible to explain all the features. After all I want to know there is any option to get previous Communication details it will help me in future also

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Not sure if it's the case for everyone, but I could check the Resolution Center messages by clicking **on the "Resolution Center" link at the bottom of the App's version details page**.

This is on the Additional Information section, below the Version Release section.

[image: Location of the Resolution Center link]

Comment: Wow, not a very intuitive place to put this link.  Thanks!

Comment: This way won't work for old versions that not appear under: iOS Versions -> Resolution Center

Comment: This is only available if that current version of the app had some review issues. It doesn't help with past versions history in the resolution center.

Comment: AppStoreConnect....com->Specific App-> App Store -> General/App Information-> Additional Information and no Resolution Center after an app is released.

Comment: Year 2021, I get a reject today, Apple said my app is similar to theirs, they want me to change design. And I found I only could open Resolution Center from the link in email. I don't see there is an additional information, maybe Apple has removed it. And I don't find reply button in Resolution Center too... So I just re-design 1 page layout and re-archive and submit again. Wait for that hacking review.

Comment: Year 2022, they added the possibility to write messages to them in the resolution center. But as @ChuckZHB noted, no link to Resolution Center in Additional Information anymore.

Answer (score 71):

You can navigate to AppReview section using this link:
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/XXXXXXXXXX/appstore/reviewsubmissions

Once you navigate to this page, you can find reviews that are completed and in progress and if in progress you can click on view to see communication exchanged between dev and app review team.

/// Below is outdated.
You can navigate to resolution center using this link:

```
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/XXXXXXXXXX/appstore/platform/ios/resolutioncenter?m=
```

Where `XXXXXXXXXX` is your app's id.

Comment: **Thank you**, this _actually worked_ where the other suggestions on this thread did not.

Comment: Great solution with best result. Thank you Avinash.

Comment: Thanks from 2021, this is worked. Don't know why Apple made that page in-transparent, we are paid member!

Comment: don't think the (empty) `m` parameter in the query string is needed, is it...? I know it's there when you open it from the email or the link provided in the release, but I tried without it and it worked just fine, no difference, wondering what it may be for...

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work anymore. Resolution Center is replaced by App Review.

Answer (score 4):

The *history of Resolution Centre communications* gets *purged* on a successful app version release, there is no way to retrieve it. 
To ensure that the `Apple Review Team` does not hinders the review process (& thereby time), mention your explanation for using a particular feature (like iTunes File Sharing) in the `Notes` section under the `App Review Information` header on the iTunes Connect panel.
If the explanation is legit & there are genuine reasons then the Review Team won't hinder the release cycle.
And, lastly do read the Store recommendation on what you should include in the `Notes` section, -

> Additional information about your app that can help during the review process. Include information that may be needed to test your app, such as app-specific settings.

Comment: This time I checked it by Keeping the resolution centre URL of my problem after my release till now the URL is valid and I can see my chat conversation with apple.

Answer (score 4):

Direct link to resolution center (and message history specifically) becomes unavailable after the app passes review successfully. However the entire chat history is still available via the original link sent by Apple Review Team (at least for some time).

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the version history is available on the "App Store" tab in Appstoreconnect:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apple has UI for this. Follow the steps

1. Select the app
2. Select App store
3. Version History under General section
4. Find resolution centre button top right corner

Comment: Top right button is your name where you edit your profile information. The word "resolution" does not appear on the web page specified

Answer (score 2):

All of the above are not working for me. Simply go to the email sent from the **App Store Connect**. Then click on the go to `Resolution Center` button in this email.

Comment: This does work but unfortunately at this time the messages don't seem to load if they have been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the version history is available on the "App Store" tab in Appstoreconnect:
[img - location link to resolution center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVlUm.png)

It is important to keep in mind that the button will only be available when your build is in status the "rejected".
Sorry, my english very bad.

Comment: If you are going to include an image with your answer, it is strongly preferred that the image be uploaded to imgur using the interface that is part of the [edit]ing or creating an answer or question here on Stack Overflow. Doing so insures that the image will remain available for as long as your post exists. When you use a 3rd party service it's likely that at some point the link will die and the image will no longer be available. Please [edit] to upload the image you are wanting to include.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Apple developer account
2. Go the App store connect
3. click on rejected app
4. on the right hand menu click on 'Version History'
5. On Version history page, you will find link of 'Resolution Center'