# Is there a step I need to take? Inconsistency in IAP status

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My In-App Purchase got rejected. I've updated the name per some other questions and the status changed on the internal page seen here.

[image: pass screenshot 1]

When I go to the main page though it still says Developer Action Needed. What action should I take?

[image: pass screenshot 2]

I just don't want to continue waiting if I need to do something else.

Comment: Check what is the reason for reject!?

Comment: The rejection was actually from the app and not the in-app purchase. There isn’t anything wrong with the IAP as far as I know. Where do you suggest looking to see otherwise?

Comment: See the first answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298183/any-option-to-view-history-of-resolution-center-communications-itunes-connect